# Sorting table reference dropdown when adding/editing entries using SQLFORM.grid

Tags: python, mysql, web2py

This is how I have my tables defined in db.py:

```
db.define('other_other_table1',
          Field('other_other1_field1', 'string',
                length=30, required=True,
                format='%(other_other1_field1)s'),
                singular='Other Other Stuff 1',
                plural='Other Other Stuff 1')


db.define('other_other_table2',
          Field('other_other2_field1', 'string',
                length=40, required=True,
                format='%(other_other2_field1)s'),
                singular='Other Other Stuff 2',
                plural='Other Other Stuff 2')


db.define_table('other_table',
                Field('other_field1',
                      'reference other_other_table1'),
                Field('other_field2', 'double'),
                Field('other_field3', 
                      'reference other_other_table2'),
                format=lambda r: '%s %s %s' % \
                             (r.other_field1.other_other1_field1,
                              str(r.other_field2),
                              r.other_field3.other_other2_field1),
                singular='Other Stuff',
                plural='Other Stuff')


db.define_table('main_table',
                Field('main_field1',
                      'reference other_table'),
                singular='Stuff',
                plural='Stuff')
```

In my controller, for main_table I have a simple action:

```
def main_table():
    grid = SQLFORM.grid(db.main_table, maxtextlength=100)

    return dict(grid=grid)
```

This works well and gives the functionality I was hoping for (which was to be able to easily add, edit, view, & delete entries in the database), but the problem I'm running into comes when adding/editing new entries in `main_table`.

When I click on the `+Add Record` button and go to the form for adding an entry into `main_table`, it shows a dropdown.  The problem is that the choices of the dropdown menu are sorted by the ID's of the entries in `other_table`, whereas instead I'd prefer for the items to be sorted alphabetically based on the format specifed in the definition of `other_table`.

Is there an way to get it to sort alphabetically like I want?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Reference fields get a default `IS_IN_DB` validator whose `label` argument is based on the `format` attribute of the referenced table (the `label` argument is used to generate labels in `<select>` widgets in forms). When the `format` attribute is a string, web2py inspects the string, extracts the field names, and uses them to build an `orderby` argument for the database query (which results in the records being ordered based on the generated labels). However, when the `format` attribute is a function, as in this case, this does not work.

Instead, you can manually specify the `IS_IN_DB` validator and set `sort=True`. This tells it to explicitly order the options by the labels.

```
db.main_table.main_field1.requires=IS_IN_DB(db, 'other_table.id',
                                            label=db.other_table._format, sort=True)
```

Comment: Thank you very much for your answer.  That was exactly what I was looking for.